# `HIVE_METASTORE_JARS` variable ignored by PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I'm running PySpark 1.6.0 against Hive 0.14. The config option `spark.sql.hive.metastore.version` is set to 0.14 but `spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars` is not set, so PySpark is trying to use the built in and failing to access Hive with the message

```
IllegalArgumentException: u'Builtin jars can only be used when hive execution version == hive metastore version. Execution: 1.2.1 != Metastore: 0.14. Specify a vaild path to the correct hive jars using $HIVE_METASTORE_JARS or change spark.sql.hive.metastore.version to 1.2.1.'
```

as expected. I set on the shell the variable `HIVE_METASTORE_JARS` to the correct folder for the Hive jars for 0.14 but PySpark ignores it. Passing it with `--jars hive-metastore.jar` does not seem to work (it hangs completely).

Is there a way to make PySpark see these jars without changing the `spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars` variable on `spark-conf`?